# My background Image won't show up on the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I am trying to create a div and add a background image to it in jQuery. For some reason, I cannot do it. If I instead make my background color white, I get a white background. Here is my code:

```
function appendToDom(poster) {
        var aPoster = $('<div>');
        aPoster.css({
                display: 'inline block',
                float: 'left',
                margin: '10px',
                marginLeft: '37px',
                marginTop: '20px',
                width: '200px',
                height: '300px',
                fontSize: '36px',
                color: 'black',
                //backgroundColor: 'white',
                backgroundSize: '200px 300px',
                backgroundImage: './../images/question.png'
            })
            /*
                    $(aPoster).attr("css","background-image: url(~/desktop/MyMovies/public/js/images/question.jpeg)");
                    $(aPoster).attr("css","background-size: 200px 300px");*/
        $(main).append(aPoster);
    }
```

Thanks for all the advice! So I took the suggestions given to me, but it still doesn't work for me.Here is a screenshot of what I have:

[my improved code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO7do.png)

NVM I got it! Thanks!

Comment: When using a url with [background-image property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) the url needs to be wrapped by `url()`, eg `url(../someimg.jpg)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your method look like this...

```
 aPoster.css({
            'display': 'inline block',
            'float': 'left',
            'margin': 10,
            'margin-left': 37,
            'margin-top': 20,
            'width': 200,
            'height': 300,
            'font-size': 36,
            'color': 'black',
            'background-color': 'white',
            'background-size': '200px 300px',
            'background-image': 'url("./../images/question.png")'
```

Try something like this and see what you get. You also notice that I got rid of the values with pixel. Because JavaScript's default values for CSS properties like that have their units in pixels. Just try it and see if it works. Hope this helped. Oh and one last thing, if you used an external script, don't forget to use the URL and make it relative to the script itself and not your main page...but in your case, the styles would be added inline to the div element so you should probably make it relative to your main page, the page where the div would be created...

Comment: _"jQuery's CSS method doesn't use camel cases for it's css properties"_ umm yes it does, you can use camel cased property names, the method will use either one, [demo showing it](https://jsfiddle.net/47xkm2ro/)

Comment: Touché...guess I've learned something new, thanks. It's just everywhere I learned about the CSS method, they didn't use the camel case. I'll edit my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

If the style is inline like in your case, the path has to be relative to the html document. Please check it.